# How to create Jackson XML POJO class for a JsonObject of JsonObjects

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I'm trying to create POJOs for the following JSON structure.  The `Fields` node is easy enough to wire up, but I'm unsure how to use annotations to wire up the `Description` node.  If I had been defining the JSON structure for that node, I'd have create an JsonArray of JsonObjects, which would make the java class easy, but since I didn't, I need to figure out how to serialize the structure below:

```
{
    "Fields": {
        "Required": ["ftp.hostname"],
        "Optional": ["ftp.rootDirectory"]
    },
    "Description": {
        "ftp.hostname": {
            "label": "SFTP Hostname",
            "description": "SFTP server hostname or IP address"
        },
        "ftp.rootDirectory": {
            "label": "Root Directory",
            "description": "The root path on the Data Store accessible by this connector"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the nodes in the `Description` object have names that correlate to the values defined in the `Fields` node, which means their node names can vary from payload to payload.

The class for the `Fields` node:

```
public class FieldDetails {

    public static final String REQUIRED = "Required";
    public static final String OPTIONAL = "Optional";

    @JsonProperty(value = REQUIRED, required = true)
    private List<String> required;

    @JsonProperty(value = OPTIONAL, required = true)
    private List<String> optional;
}
```

And what I have so far for the entire object:

```
public class FieldDefinitions {

    public static final String FIELDS = "Fields";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

    @JsonProperty(value = FIELDS, required = true)
    private FieldDetails fields;

    @JsonProperty(value = DESCRIPTION , required = true)
    private ??? descriptions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can always map any `JSON` object to `Map<String, Object>`. If `JSON` is complicated with many nested objects, `Jackson` will automatically pick correct type: `Map` for objects and `List` for arrays.

You can also declare class like below for `Description` properties.

```
class Description {
    private String label;
    private String description;
    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

The whole `Description` is a big `JSON` which you can map to `Map<String, Description>`. So, it could look like below:

```
class FieldDefinitions {

    public static final String FIELDS = "Fields";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

    @JsonProperty(value = FIELDS, required = true)
    private FieldDetails fields;

    @JsonProperty(value = DESCRIPTION, required = true)
    private Map<String, Description> descriptions;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Rest is the same. Example app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File json = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        FieldDefinitions fields = mapper.readValue(json, FieldDefinitions.class);
        System.out.println("Required");
        fields.getFields().getRequired().forEach(r ->
                System.out.println(r + " = " + fields.getDescriptions().get(r)));
        System.out.println("Optional");
        fields.getFields().getOptional().forEach(r ->
                System.out.println(r + " = " + fields.getDescriptions().get(r)));
    }
}
```

For given `JSON` `payload` prints:

```
Required
ftp.hostname = Description{label='SFTP Hostname', description='SFTP server hostname or IP address'}
Optional
ftp.rootDirectory = Description{label='Root Directory', description='The root path on the Data Store accessible by this connector'}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the structure.

```
public class FieldDefinitions {
    @JsonProperty("Fields")
    public FieldDetails fields = new FieldDetails();

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    public Map<String, Property> properties = new HashMap<>();
}

public class FieldDetails {
    @JsonProperty("Required")
    public List<String> required = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("Optional")
    public List<String> optional = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Property {
    public String label;
    public String description;
}
```